# What is the role of representation theory?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, rotations

This question is a bit vague mostly because of my very limited knowledge of group theory. But I would like to know if there is some intuitive example of representation theory that gives a layman an 'a-ha' moment.

Let us just consider the group $SO(2)$ and denote the representations by $\left|m \right>$ for $m=0,\pm 1, \pm 2, ...$. Then for some generator $J$ we have $J\left|m \right>=\left|m \right> m$, and for a rotation by $\phi$ we have $$U^m(\phi)\left|m \right>=\left|m \right> e^{-im\phi}$$
where rotation by $\phi$ get mapped to $U^m(\phi)$, $R(\phi) \rightarrow U^m(\phi)$.

**Why have all these representations? Don't I just need $m=1$, the so called faithful representation?**

Of course there is the Fourier analysis picture and that I get a localized $\left|\phi\right>$ by summing over all these representations,
$$ \left|\phi\right>=\sum_m \left|m\right>e^{-im\phi}$$
which is kind of saying "rotate by $\phi$ in all representations", is that expressing $\phi$ as group member (or an 'action') as opposed to just a plain angle? Obviously something is gained by having these **degenerate representations** $-$ but shouldn't all the information be already available in the faithful representation?

Comment: I'm not really qualified for a complete answer to this question, but ponder: why should one ever consider any group action other than the (left) regular action? That action contains all the information you ever need about the group. Of course, it turns out that by considering different actions, you bring out different interesting properties of the group and how it behaves.

Comment: I guess one of the things that would really help me understand things is how insights from simple Fourier series/transform manifest themselves in this world of 'angles-as-actions' and representations. For example does $\sum_n U^n(\phi) U^\dagger_n(\phi') = \delta(\phi-\phi')$ have any interpretation in terms of applying a series of actions?